# Open Telemetry Context Tracing for Apache and/or Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, open-telemetry

We are implementing distributed tracing in our environment, starting with simple auto-instrumentation, using Open Telemetry.  Our environment is primarily cloud based, running on AWS.

We have had success auto-instrumenting most of our cloud services (ECS, EKS, Lambda, etc.), and are seeing context tracing being passed from one service to the next.  We are also auto-instrumenting Apache and Nginx servers running on EC2, using the Otel standard, and are successfully seeing trace information being collected, but calls from Apache to another front-end or back-end service are not being tied together by trace context.  Apache produces it's own trace id and the system it calls is producing it's own as well, and the linkage is lost.

Has anybody been able to get this to work and are there samples you can share?

Thanks so much!

We have tried using the Otel libraries, as well as the AWS distributed tracing libraries, and have played around with different exporters and collectors.  The tracing capabilities work individually, but when it comes time to pass context from Apache and/or Nginx to some other service, the trace link is broken

Answer (score 0):

For Apache and Nginx, there are existing modules that can be used, likely you're using those already:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/httpd
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/nginx

By default, context is not propagated, probably that's why your traces aren't tied together.

For the Apache module, you'd need to set the [`OpenTelemetryPropagators`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/httpd#configuration) option in the [configuration file](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/blob/main/instrumentation/httpd/opentelemetry.conf#L27):

```
OpenTelemetryPropagators trace-context
```

For Nginx, you'll also need to add explicit `opentelemetry_propagate` directives to routes to enable context propagation (here's a [detailed example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/nginx#usage)):

```
location = / {
  opentelemetry_operation_name my_example_backend;
  opentelemetry_propagate;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3500/;
}
```

If you want Apache and Nginx to continue traces based on incoming context, you need to additionally set [`OpenTelemetryIgnoreInbound`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/httpd#configuration) for Apache and [`opentelemetry_trust_incoming_spans`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/nginx#opentelemetry_trust_incoming_spans) for Nginx.